# How to validate a user using OAuth2

Tags: java, netbeans, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an application and various users registered to this application. I am registering user to my application using *Google service*. When user tries to log in, I am validating the user using `OAuth1` authorization mechanism using user ***emailId*** and ***password***

Below is the code which I was using for authorizing user,

```
public static RestResponse accountsClientLogin(String accountType, String email, String passwd, String service, String source) throws IOException {
        String apiKey = GoogleAccountsServiceAuthenticator.getApiKey();
        String[][] pathParams = new String[][]{};
        String[][] queryParams = new String[][]{{"accountType", accountType}, {"Email", email}, {"Passwd", passwd}, {"service", service}, {"source", source}};
        RestConnection conn = new RestConnection("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", pathParams, null);
        sleep(1000);
        return conn.post(null, queryParams);
    }
```

above code is perfectly working for me, but as Google shifted from `OAuth1` to `OAuth2`, I also have to shift to `OAuth2`.

I am confused how to do above stuff using `OAuth2`. I went through many links but all was application specific, I want to validate user using ***emailId*** and ***password*** as I did in previous version of my application. How can I migrate from `OAuth1` to `OAuth2`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ClientLogin and not OAuth 1.0. I would recommend switching to OAuth 2.0. You can use Apache Oltu library for OAuth 2.0 support. I can help you with sample code, if you plan to do that.

Comment: hey thanks Saqib, but I am using Google OAuth. Can you provide me the sample code using `Google OAuth2`. That would be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Cant use comment feature that's why writing my suggestions directly in answer.

This link might help you understand how auth 2.0 works with google.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect

Actually google uses open id connect as a mechanism to authenticate user for you. what you need  to do is redirect user to google auth server, user will login on google, then user will be redirected back to your application and with redirection url your application will receive a random string called token.
With the help of this token you can call google rest apis to get user info like who actually logged in to google during redirection and hence you know the logged in user.

Here is the demo on github https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.17/examples/oauth2-client-google-webapp

To run the demo you need to register application with google which identifies your application uniquely.

Comment: Hey @Ashutosh, thanks for your clear explanation. It helps me to visualize the problem more clearly. I went through the link provided by you [ i.e. [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect)  ] . But I am facing problem in **exchangeCode** [ step no 4. [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode) ]. Its giving me 400 with json 
{
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}. I have mentioned a grant_type as `authorization_code`. How cal I figure it out?

Comment: @Ravindra Please make sure there are no line breaks or spaces in parameters.This is the first request https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=openid%20email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri&state=8856eaba-9f01-47a8-bbc9-dbb926bde88b&client_id=your_client_id&prompt=consent , second request i.e. step 4 - POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_secret=your_client_secrete&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri&code=code_recieved_in_first_step&client_id=your_client_id

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do this all yourself, Google has two options:

The [Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/) if you want to support multiple identity providers (plus plain email & password).

And [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/) if you just want a "Sign-in with Google" function.